# log4j2 - Different layouts for different levels in one appender

Tags: xml, log4j, log4j2

I want to have one appender with different layouts for different message levels. All the solutions I've came up with need two different appenders like here:

```
<Appender type="Console" name="STDOUT_D">
    <Layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="[%-5p] %d %c - %m%n"/>
    <Filters>
         <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="ACCEPT"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
         <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="ACCEPT"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
         <ThresholdFilter level="warn"  onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
         <ThresholdFilter level="info"  onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
         <ThresholdFilter level="debug"  onMatch="ACCEPT"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    </Filters>
</Appender>
<Appender type="Console" name="STDOUT">
     <Layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="[%-5p] %d %-60.60c - %m%n"/>
     <Filters>
         <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
         <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
         <ThresholdFilter level="warn"  onMatch="ACCEPT"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
         <ThresholdFilter level="info"  onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
         <ThresholdFilter level="debug"  onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
     </Filters>
</Appender>
```

Ideas?

I'm using XML config with strict mode on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've archieved this result using ScriptPatternSelector

```
<Appender type="Console" name="STDOUT">
    <PatternLayout>
    <ScriptPatternSelector defaultPattern="[%-5level] %c{1.} %C{1.}.%M.%L %msg%n">
        <Script name="selector" language="groovy"><![CDATA[
            if (logEvent.getLevel() == org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.DEBUG)
                return "DEBUG"
            else
                return "INFO"
          ]]>
        </Script>
        <PatternMatch key="DEBUG" pattern="[%-5p] %d %c - %m%n"/>
        <PatternMatch key="INFO" pattern="[%-5p] %d %-60.60c - %m%n"/>
    </ScriptPatternSelector>
    </PatternLayout>
</Appender>
```